# crtmqm give no response

Tags: ibm-mq, mq

I try to create a WebSphere queue manager in production env. Before this I manage to create the queue manager in the development env with no problem.

I'm using this script to create the queue manager:

`crtmqm -u SYSTEM.DEAD.LETTER.QUEUE test1.qm`

But it give no response (no error or success message).
When I try to start the queue manager (`strmqm test1.qm`) it give

"AMQ8118: WebSphere MQ queue manager does not exist."

Then I notice lots of strange thing that supposed not happen:

1. I can run the "crtmqm -u SYSTEM.DEAD.LETTER.QUEUE test1.qm" several times without any error
2. I can just type crtmqm and got no response
3. I can type crtmqm -y (which is not possible since there is no -y argument) and still no response

Can anyone tell me what is wrong?

Comment: Please provide more detail.  For example, what platform is this on?  What user ID was used to run the command?  What version of WMQ?  What do you get back from `dspmqver`?  You said you were runnning crtmqm from a script - was STDERR or STDOUT redirected at the time?

Answer (score 0):

If you are on UNIX, it may be that the OS kernel parameter requirements have not been met. Check the relevant WMQ Quick Beginnings manual for the platform.